# Pulling text from another text field in MS-access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I'm not 100% sure how to even word my issue!! i have a field with text in (auto populated from a report) its in the format of "Home/area/process/" is there a quick way of extracting the area text.

Its always the same at the beginning but after area it could be "/process/more processes" or even "/information/more information" so i cant pull something which is simply "extract everything between "Home/ and /process"

hopefully this make sense i have about 9000 entries to do this for :)

thanks in advance everyone, I'm open to VBA / queries anything for Access 2007!

Comment: The keyword would be "parsing" a string. Check out the Split function [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/split.php). Your delimiter would be "/". You can also use a combination of string functions to achieve the same thing, [see here](http://access.mvps.org/access/strings/str0001.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Dim exampleString As String
Dim exampleArray() As String

exampleString = [field containing the string you want to split]
exampleArray = Split(exampleString,"/")
```

So for example, if you have the following string in the field you mentioned: `home/area/process`

And the field name is `txtField`, which is in a report named `rptSummary`

Then you could do the following:

```
Dim exampleString As String
Dim exampleArray() As String

exampleString = Reports!rptSummary!txtField.Value
exampleArray = Split(exampleString, "/")
```

You could then access all of the indices of `exampleArray` and do with them what you please. For example, if you wanted to create a popup showing the contents of each index in `exampleArray`, you could do the following:

```
MsgBox exampleArray(0) //Creates a message box popup that displays "home"
MsgBox exampleArray(1) //...displays "area"
MsgBox exampleArray(2) //...displays "process"
```

You could also use the `Mid` function, which requires a bit more detail. Information on that [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/mid.php).

In order to be any more specific than that, we'd need more information regarding field names, report names, are forms involved, etc.

Comment: Thanks for this, i've used VBA a bit in excel but not access.  essentially the "home/area/process" is the location of a document in another system and i need to extract the area it belongs to.  is there a way i can add ExampleArray(1) to a Field in my table (tblDocuments) called "Area"?  Big thanks for this so far!

Comment: Quick up after spending the morning researching i think the easiest way is using the mid function so far i have remove everything before the first "/" using [Mid([documents.Location],InStr([documents.Location],"/")+1) AS Area] now i need to work on removing everything after the second "/"  thanks for the help and pointers

Comment: Assuming everything will always be separated by the delimiter "/", using the `Split` function and just calling up `exampleArray(1)` (or whatever you want to call it), would likely be cleaner and definitely easier to work with than parsing multiple times with the `Mid` function. For instance, in response to your first comment reply, you could write some SQL and execute it in VBA (assign the SQL statement to a string variable, execute the statement using `DoCmd.RunSQL`) to append `exampleArray(1)` to a table.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this by creating 2 queries and adding the following to the to a new field - one to remove the first part of the string "Home/"

`firstArea: Mid([tblDocuments.Location],InStr([tblDocuments.Location],"/")+1)`

then using this query I've created another to just display the next section before the "/" (using just the first result added everything else after the area i.e. the "/process bit"

```
Area: Left([All docs with area.firstArea],InStr([All docs with area.firstArea],"/")-1)
```

not the neatest way I'm sure and there are a few errors for documents with nothing in the "/Process" section but overall works.

thanks for the pointers, I'm now armed with Parsing strings knowledge :)